# Writing a value to 7-segment max7219 displays

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, lcd, display

I am new to arduino and I am trying to build an interface for my flight simulator. I am using a plugin for the simulator software which returns a float variable to my arduino, which I then want to display on a series of 7-segment displays. I have connected three max7219 modules, each with 8 digits.

I found the LedControl library which I managed to get to display on my modules like this:

```
#include <LedControl.h>

// inputs: DIN pin, CLK pin, LOAD pin. number of chips
LedControl mydisplay = LedControl(48, 44, 46, 3);

void setup() {
  mydisplay.shutdown(0, false);  // turns on display
  mydisplay.shutdown(1, false);  // turns on display
  mydisplay.setIntensity(0, 7); // 15 = brightest
  mydisplay.setDigit(0, 0, 9, false);
  mydisplay.setDigit(0, 1, 8, false);
  mydisplay.setDigit(0, 2, 7, false);
  mydisplay.setDigit(0, 3, 6, false);
  mydisplay.setDigit(0, 4, 5, true);
  mydisplay.setDigit(0, 5, 4, false);
  mydisplay.setDigit(0, 6, 3, false);
  mydisplay.setDigit(0, 7, 2, false);

  mydisplay.setDigit(1, 0, 9, false);
  mydisplay.setDigit(1, 1, 8, false);
  mydisplay.setDigit(1, 2, 7, false);
  mydisplay.setDigit(1, 3, 6, false);
  mydisplay.setDigit(1, 4, 5, true);
  mydisplay.setDigit(1, 5, 4, false);
  mydisplay.setDigit(1, 6, 3, false);
  mydisplay.setDigit(1, 7, 2, false);

}

void loop() {
}
```

The arduino code however for the plugin I am using has this function:

```
void ProgOut(byte id, float val) {

  if (id == 1)
  {
       // print this to display
  } 
}
```

So my question is, right now based on the LedControl test sketch, I have to display each individual character one by one, but I receive a float variable.. so how can I just do something like "mydisplay.set(floatvariable)" ?

Comment: Why not use a library that supports that directly? https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-LCD. Then you can write code like "led.print(3.1415, 4)", i.e. use the same interface as Serial.

Comment: I didn't know about that library. I'll check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I just do something like "mydisplay.set(floatvariable)" ?

write your own code.

let's say that you want to display up to two decimal points. Multiply the float vary by 100, save it into an int variable, and utilize the existing code to display that integer variable + decimal point at the right digit.